# Upgrade to Ubuntu 10.10 failed because of a deb file cannot be downloaded

Tags: ubuntu, updates

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 and excited to head off to 10.10.
The problem is when I tried to perform upgrade using `update-manager -d`, when all but the last file were all downloaded, suddenly the update manager failed to download the file `http://ftp.udc.es/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/orc/liborc-0.4-0_0.4.5-1_amd64.deb`
When I went to `http://ftp.udc.es/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/orc/`, I could see the `liborc-0.4-0_0.4.5-1_amd64.deb` is actually listed here, but it unavailable when I tried to click on it. Have any one encounter this before? How can I work around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the update servers and try again
[image]

---

When Update Manager asks for whether it should perform a Partial Update or not, select No and then choose Upgrade in the next Dialog. Ubuntu will then update as much as possible. After that, you can switch to a different server.

Comment: I cannot change it. The source will be automatically reverted to 'Main Server'

Comment: There should be an option to automatically select the best server, use that @Phuong

Comment: It doesn't matter which server I choose. Dist-upgrade will always pull stuff from Main Server.

Comment: It's interesting. When UpdataManager ask for whether it should perform a Partial Update or not, I select No and then choose Upgrade in the next Dialog. Ubuntu will then update as much as possible. After that, I can switch to a different server. I think you can modify your answer to include this notice and then I will mark it as an answer.

Comment: @Phuong updated with your comment.